# Mysql WorkBench Importar e Exportar

Tags: importação, exportação, mysql

Tenho uma Banco no MySQL Workbench com os dados preenchidos e quero passar esses dados todos preenchidos para outro MySQL Workbench, mas em outro computador.

É possível fazer isso ou terei de preencher os dados todos novamente?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode exportar o seu banco no Workbench em `Management`-> `Data Export`. Selecionar a database, escolha o diretório e nome do arquivo e clique em `Start Export`. Será gerado um arquivo sql.

Em outro computador, no Workbench, clique em `Management`-> `Data Import/Restore`, procure o arquivo sql gerado anteriormente e clique em `Start Import`.

Este é a versão 6.1 do MySQL Workbench.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$hostname = "localhost";
$dbname   = "test";

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($dbname . "_" .date("Y-m-d_H-i-s").".sql"));

$command = "C:\AppServ\MySQL\bin\mysqldump --add-drop-table --host=$hostname     --user=$username --password=$password ".$dbname;

system($command);
?>
```

Comment: se o banco de dados for local você pode usar o código acima